# XSS bug in mobile link

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, xss

**I'm totally frustrated. I reported this using the procedure mentioned in the FAQ but the confirmation email sent me back to the original form.**

There is XSS on every page of Stack Overflow. Injecting `,alert(1),` into the path executes when clicking on the mobile version of the site.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/%22,alert%281%29,%22</strike>.
2. Click on the mobile link in the footer.

The mobile link is incorrectly escaped for the context the data is in.

```
<a onclick='StackExchange.switchMobile("on", "/&quot;,alert(1),&quot;")'>mobile</a>
```

HTML entities will still break out of the string since the data is inside an attribute resulting in the function being called.

Comment: I assume you sent the report [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) first? What you mean "confirmation email sent me back to the original form"? When did you send the report and what exact reply you got?

Comment: I used the contact form http://stackoverflow.com/contact as described as a way to report vulnerabilities. The response I got back directed me back to the same form.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't automatic response just to confirm your report has been sent? When did you send it? I find it really hard to believe the team will ignore such report.

Comment: Is it coincidence that I'm currently reading the XSS wikipedia article when this poped up?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Conspiracy!

Comment: @JohannesKuhn hurry up, now that you know XSS you can steal all the cookies! ;-)

Comment: I would generally just send security issues like this directly too `team@stackexchange.com`; ignore whatever the contact form says.

Comment: mmmmmmm cookies

Comment: Good catch. I'd checked that link before but didn't realize the consequences of the escaping they'd used.

Comment: Did you not see [a message like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uYuBc.png) after submitting the contact form?

Comment: Yes and my email response linked me back to the same contact form.

Comment: Would you mind going into further detail about what the confirmation email says? That may be a UX issue worth discussing on its own.

Comment: @GarethHeyes I don't understand why you refuse to tell us **when did you send the report**. If it was only short while ago, just give them some time.

Comment: I reported it last week.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I'll send you the text when I get home tonight. I don't have the email to hand right now.

Comment: OK so it's weird that you didn't get any real support there. Curious too to see the exact text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and trying to do the right thing - responsible disclosure via [our requested channel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports) - we take security vulnerabilities very seriously.

I don't know what exactly happened and why you have only gotten a confirmation email and nothing else, I will be chasing this up internally and ensure this does not recur.

In other news, as you have noted, the XSS vulnerability has been fixed.

Comment: I have blogged about this, if anyone is interested: http://odedcoster.com/blog/2013/12/15/anatomy-of-a-xss-vulnerability-on-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 15):

My apologies, Gareth - we do take these reports very seriously, and make *sure* each one is reviewed and responded to by a Real, Live Human™.

Unfortunately, when you emailed us we'd *just* rolled out a [new set of instructions](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) for reporting these, and there was a bit of confusion over how reports should be handled as a result.

(to be specific: we didn't immediately realize that it pointed back at the same "contact" form used for *every other* "contact us" link)

Again, I sincerely apologize for the confusion; thanks for being persistent!

Comment: Just rolled out? The page exists for [at least two months](http://web.archive.org/web/20130929093846/http://stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports)... what did I miss?

Comment: I used the wrong link, @Sha. The new page was put up on the 4th or thereabouts, the same day Gareth contacted us. Note that while the old page has a simple link to "contact us", the *new* page has a Big Red Button on it. Which... goes to the same place. Such a tease.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - At least two months... aka 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: Thanks for fixing but still, nothing new regarding the reporting procedure itself as far as I can see... unless you mean something changed behind the scenes where you handle those reports?

Comment: That's because there *isn't* anything new regarding the actual procedures: it's still "1) verify report (if possible), 2) forward to the dev team". We don't do automated responses or priority queues or anything else like that; this was simply a bit of confusion caused by poor communication internally - even though the new page *looks* like it does something different, it was (and is) supposed to be handled in exactly the same manner as the old page. @Sha

Comment: Fair enough. So you mean the OP here got response saying "Please report this using [link to form here]"?

Comment: Correct, @Sha. Which of course, took him right back to where he started.

Comment: Oh, endless loop. Wonderful! ;)

Comment: It's all good until your stack overflows.